# Could not load file or assembly (one of my project's dlls, which exists)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a winforms app whcih calls a wcf service. In the wcf service, I have this error:

Could not load file or assembly (and then details of an assembly which is one of my projects).

This started happening out of the blue, how can I ensure that the assembly loads?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to find out why your assembly is not loading.

Comment: I second this. The Fusion log is overlooked by a lot of developers. It's saved me a few times.

Answer (score 1):

This is out of the blue, but I ran into this problem when I started using VS2010.  When you create a new project like a winforms app or console app the default .net type is set by VS as .net 4 Client Profile.  For whatever reason, when the project is set to this .net framework, some libraries will not load and all you will get is the above error message when trying to compile, in my case it would never load the Castle Windsor libraries I use in all of my projects, the fix being set it to .NET 4 only (no client profile) or .NET 3.5 by going to the project in Solution Explorer -> properties, then set the .net framework.